# VM Clarity - clrForm select input

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

How can I use a select input in the new form (clrForm) structure?

I'm using Clarity version 0.12.4. They have introduced some new form structure.
It's quite nice but I cant'get the select input to work..

Comment: Have you followed the setup for new forms? https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/forms

Comment: Yes, i did but i noticed that they removed the select examples from the documentation so I think it’s not possible

Comment: The select has not been built for Angular yet, so its is upcoming yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of Clarity is still under progress.

However, I got this working., Its pretty straight forward.

Similar to input, you need to add 'clrInput' directive to select and put the entire select inside clr-input-container tag.

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <clr-input-container>
        <label>Landmark</label>
        <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="landmark" name="landmark" required maxlength="200"/>
        <clr-control-error *clrIfError="'minLength'">Must be less than 200 characters</clr-control-error>
      </clr-input-container>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="select">
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>City</label>
          <select clrInput id="city" [(ngModel)]="city" name="city">
            <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </clr-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="select">
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>City</label>
          <select clrInput id="state" [(ngModel)]="state" name="city">
            <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.id">{{state.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </clr-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PS: Don't forget to add 'ClarityModule' and 'ClrFormsNextModule' in imports of your module.

Comment: In current clr 0.12 `<div class="select">` is not necessary.